# Cannot download file - java, downloadmanager, API 28

Tags: android, android-download-manager

For last 48 hours I'm trying to solve that, I have went through number of examples ... and still nothing. I'm trying to add to my app single file download - later it will be triggered by RabbitMQ, but currently - for testing purposes I would like to do it using buttonClick, on below example I have skipped any additional parameters (such as Description, Title etc. ... ). After click I receive information that Download Manager was not able to download the file, of course file exist on the link (I can download it without any issue from phone browser).

```
public void downloadFile2(View view) {
            if(PermissionCheck.readAndWriteExternalStorage(this)) {
                DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager)this.getSystemService(this.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://xxxxxx/File1.pdf");
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"/File1.pdf");
                downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
            }
        }
```

**Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS** - I have tried mutliple Directory Downloads, but none worked
**setDestinationInExternalPublicDir** (I have laso tried setDestinationInExternalFilesDir - no luck

```
package com.example.majap;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

    public class PermissionCheck {
        public static boolean readAndWriteExternalStorage(Context context) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And of course in manifest I have (even to much)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: probably the different is on .... other side - on my python webserver, I don't know why but probably downloadmanager doesn't accept "send_from_directory" build on python3 flask.... still investigating that ...

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days, and 28 coffees - I found solution:

```
<application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

as from  Android 8 - Cleartext HTTP traffic is not permitted